# Multiple Rows Won't Paste From Excel to SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: custom-list, copy-and-paste

I can only paste one row at a time from an Excel sheet (.xls) into a datasheet view of a custom sharepoint list. The columns match exactly and all of the column types are set to "single line of text".

All rows paste successfully if done one at a time, the error only occurs if multiple are selected.
This has worked previously but for some reason I get the below error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure following:

- excel table and your datasheet view line up exactly.
- Don't have any "Created by," "Attachments" or "Last Modified" fields on there.
- Make your selection within Excel, and then in datasheet, ONLY click into the top, leftmost field, (rather than making a paste selection)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bb38070e-9a0a-4dd7-9851-a5afb522f331/unable-to-paste-multi-rows-from-excel-to-datasheet-view-in-sharepoint-2010-list?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but that's OK, its still relevant.
Our issue was similar excel not pasting into a sharepoint list.
Two possible causes we are aware of....

Number one.
In sharepoint, is the cell highlighted, no blinking cursor?  (good)
In sharepoint, is the cell highlighted, and has blinking cursor?  (bad)
if the sharepoint cell has the blinking cursor averything will get pasted into that cell.

Number two
What we found was that excel Online will not want to paste correctly blinking cursor or not.  Load the excel sheet into the desktop version of excel and copy from there.  Should then work just fine.